# How can I disable the blinking cursor in SciTE?

Tags: editor, autohotkey

I just installed the SciTE text editor as it was recommended for AutoHotkey syntax highlighting.

However, I can't handle the blinking cursor, and SciTE does not obey the cursor settings on my Windows system, which are set to 'no blink'.  Nor does it allow me to change the settings that I can find.

I've looked online and through the 'Options' and all the entries on the menu bar, but I found no references.

How can I disable it/prevent the cursor from blinking?

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Comment: `caret.period=0` in the options file.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!  Please make this an answer so I can give you credit!

Comment: I'd toss @wOxxOm an obligatory upvote, too. :P

Answer (score 2):

In your installation directory, exist a file named `SciTEGlobal.properties`. Open it and as suggested by wOxxOm find the line `caret.period` and change it's value to `0`